# How to calculate how many items will fit in a box using MOD?

Tags: java, math, modulo

so I am trying to finish my school project but I am stuck in the last process. I need to print the total price and the amount of boxes and the price of each. The user needs to input how many bags of coffee he wants, each bag costs 1000, and there are 3 boxes to pack them in, a large box fits 20 bags, medium box fits 10 bags and a small box fits 5 bags of coffee. Each box costs 5000,3000 and 1000 respectively. I know I need to use MOD to determine how many will go in each box but to be honest I dont even know where to start! Help? This is what I've done so far, I am having issues with Case D.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operaciones{
  String opcion="";
  int num;
  int d=2;

  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  public Operaciones(){}

  public void Opciones(){

    String MenuPrincipal=("Seleccione lo que desea hacer: "
                            +"\n A- Factores Primos"
                            +"\n B- Imprimir Patron"
                            +"\n C- Signo Zodiacal"
                            +"\n D- Calcular Pedido"
                            +"\n E- Salir");
    do{
      System.out.println(MenuPrincipal);
      opcion=sc.next();

      switch(opcion) {
        case "A":
        case "a":
          System.out.println("Factores Primos: Por favor ingrese un numero");
          num=sc.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Los Factores Primos del numero ingresado son:");

          while(num!=1){
            if(num%d==0){

              System.out.println(d+"");
              num=num/d;
            }else{
              d=d+1;
            }
          }
          break;
        case "B":
        case "b":
          System.out.println("Patron de 10 a 49");
          for(int i = 10; i <= 49; i++){
            System.out.println(i+);
          }
          break;
        case "C":
        case "c":
          String mes;
          int dia=0;
          System.out.println("Tu signo Zodiacal");
          System.out.println("En que mes naciste?");
          mes=sc.next();
          System.out.println("En que dia naciste?");
          dia=sc.nextInt();
          if((mes.equals("Enero"))||(mes.equals("enero"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=20){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Capricornio");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Febrero"))||(mes.equals("febrero"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=19){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Marzo"))||(mes.equals("marzo"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=20){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Abril"))||(mes.equals("abril"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=20){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Mayo"))||(mes.equals("mayo"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=20){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Junio"))||(mes.equals("junio"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=21){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Julio"))||(mes.equals("julio"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=22){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Agosto"))||(mes.equals("agosto"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=21){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Setiembre"))||(mes.equals("setiembre"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=23){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Octubre"))||(mes.equals("octubre"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=23){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Noviembre"))||(mes.equals("noviembre"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=22){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          if((mes.equals("Diciembre"))||(mes.equals("diciembre"))){
            if(dia>0 && dia<=22){
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Acuario");
            }else{
              System.out.println("Tu signo zodiacal es Piscis");
            }
          }
          break;
        case "D":
        case "d":
          double bolsas=0;
          double Cg=5000;
          double Cm=3000;
          double Cp=1000;
          double precioxB=1000;
          double precioBolsas=0;
          System.out.println("Cuantas bolsas desea ordenar?");
          bolsas=sc.nextInt();
          precioBolsas=bolsas*precioxB;

      }
    }while(opcion!="E");




  }
}
```

Comment: If the user orders 10 bags, should they be packed into one medium size box at 3000, or better into two small boxes at 1000? The latter is cheaper, only 2000.

Comment: Since you are reading an integer into `bolsas` (which makes sense), you should declare the variable an `int` too (not a `double`).

Comment: The user needs to get the least amount of boxes possible and the best price. So to answer your question yes. I just dont know how to figure out which box he needs and how many. Like if he asks for 50 bags, he should get 2 big boxes and 1 medium.

Comment: So since 20 bags go into a big box, `bolsas / 20` will give you a first shot at how many big boxes you will need (only works correctly if `bolsas` is an integer, though, therefore my comment). And you are correct, next you need modulo (mod): `bolsas % 20` will give you how many bags don’t fit into the first big boxes you’ve taken. If this remainder is greater than 15, just take one more big box and you’re done (think about why this is the best solution). Now, if there are still remaining bags, do something similar with 10 instead of 20 for the medium size boxes. And so on.

Comment: Thanks. Won't I need to use a loop statement and maybe a counter so it can tell me exactly how many of each box the user needs?

Comment: I wouldn’t use a loop. It’s an option of it works better for you. I’d use a number of if-else statements. I might use an auxiliary method for some of the calculations, again, it’s optional.